# Dynamically create an integer array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically create an array with user input.  I know how to initialize an array but I don't know how to allow the user to initialize one.  here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.print("Enter the size of the array (3 to 10): ");
        Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size_of_array = user_input.nextInt();
        while(size_of_array < 3 || size_of_array > 10) {
            System.out.println("The size of the array entered is invalid.");
            System.out.print("\nEnter the size of the array (3 to 10): ");
            user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
            size_of_array = user_input.nextInt();
        }
        ArrayList array = new ArrayList(size_of_array);
        System.out.println("Initial size of array: " + array.size());



    }

}
```

I thought `ArrayList array = new ArrayList(size_of_array);` was going to do the trick but the size of the array is still 0.  Hopefully someone can help me out.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're looking to use an array, why are you creating an ArrayList? With arrays, you can use the user input to set it's size at start - `int[] arr = new int[size_of_array]`

Comment: I figured an array list was easier to work with because it's dynamic but it seems like an array list is not what I'm looking for... newbie here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question if want to create dynamic size array then use

```
int array[]=new int[size_of_array];
```

And if create ArrayList then it is already a dynamic size no need to specified size.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>(size_of_array);
```

if you do this then you are defining capacity of ArrayList which is auto increment when initial capacity is full.

and when you add elements in your list like

```
array.add(45);
```

then its size increase and it not show you 0.

Answer (score 1):

An array list is dynamic in size, so you don't need to assign a size to it. When you initially create the list, the size is 0. To create the list, all you do is:

```
//Make sure you define the type of data you want to store in your list
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("Your String"); 
myList.size(); //returns a value of 1
```

If you don't add any elements to it, then the size will stay at 0. After you add an element to it, you can call the `size()` method.

If you want to use an array, you would need to allow the user to set the variable size and do something like this:

```
 user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
 size_of_array = user_input.nextInt();
 String[] stringArray = new String[size_of_array];
```

Comment: what if it was not an array list? what if it was just an array?

Comment: If it's not an array list, then you need to define the size. If you don't know what the size is going to be, I'd recommend using an `ArrayList`

Comment: How do I allow the user to define the size?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify size to `ArrayList` which is part of `Collections` like this

```
List<X> list = Arrays.asList(new X[desiredSize]);
// where X is any Object type (including arrays and enums,
// but excluding primitives)
```

The resulting list is modifiable, but not resizable (i.e. `add(e)` and `remove(e)` don't work, but `set(index, e)` does).